# Does tensorflow_addons conflict with tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-addons

I'm able to run an ANN model using tensorflow and keras as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense
firstModel = Sequential()
```

Since I need to use RSquared metric (R2), I installed tensorflow_addons to my conda environment too. Now, even **without** importing tensorflow_addons I get a long error message on the import tensorflow as tf line, the last line says:

AlreadyExistsError: Another metric with the same name already exists.

How can I fix the issue? Is there another way to get R2 rather than :
import tensorflow_addons
from tensorflow_addons.metrics import RSquare

Comment: Please provide us some more details like -  the installed `TensorFlow`, `Keras`, `python` and `TensorFlow addons` version in your system to understand the conflicts. This seems to be a version mismatch issue among these packages.